# Phone stuck in ADB sideload

Tags: adb, side-loading

I recently try to reset my android phone by power off, power on and volume up button.

There're several option but once I push volume down once and volume up once, it stuck with alarm sign and android logo. Below the logo said

> Now send the package you want to apply to the device with `adb sideload <filename>.zip`...'

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: "_but once I push volume down once and volume up once_" -- I think you did volume down once and then, the power button.

Comment: Background: From the description, you've entered "ADB sideload" mode. Entering a menu is done by pushing the menu button.

Answer (score 2):

if you can't take out the battery of your device and if longpressing whatever does not solve it

1. install adb on pc.
2. connect device with usb cable to pc
3. enter following command on pc

   ```
   adb sideload /dev/null
   ```

the device will complain that file is not valid but it will come out of the sideloading state

Comment: My ADB complains that ADB is not authorized. Now what?

Comment: i do not know what to do when adb says not authorized. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Long press Power & volumn UP button for 10 second should solve it.