# How to exit `adb sideload` mode in recovery mode?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, side-loading

I accidentally chose to apply a package with `adb sideload`.

[image]

I have tried pressing all the necessary buttons at once but nothing seems to be working.

How do I exit?

Comment: What happens if you press and hold the power button for several seconds? IIRC that should cause a reboot even in this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Phone stuck in ADB sideload](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/123569/44325). Let us know if the existing answers help or not, thanks!

Comment: just sideload something?